# Create a recurring date range in emacs diary sexp

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to create a diary sexp to use within an org mode file that will show an entry if it falls **between** the first day of the month and the first Sunday of the month.

I know how to show an entry on the first day of the month using a diary sexp with

```
%%(diary-date t 1 t) entry for first day of every month
```

I know how to show an entry on the first Sunday of the month using with

```
%%(diary-float t 0 1) entry for first Sunday of every month
```

But what about the days in between these dates? How can I include them in the expression?